# Deinit never be called if UIViewController using in Embed Segue of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIViews which embed from two types of UIViewController

ex:

```
MyVC      -> Left  View (NavigationController -> LeftViewController)
          -> Right View (NavigationController -> RightViewController)
```

I found deinit never be called in LeftViewController & RightViewController

MyVC is fine, how can I do ?

Comment: Do you have something like a delegate from `LeftViewController` to `MyVC`? If it is, could you show us how you declare this delegate ?

Comment: I just found it earlier, but you are right! :)